# is raven.contrib.django.handlers.SentryHandler async?

Tags: python, logging, asynchronous, raven

it say [here](http://raven.readthedocs.org/en/latest/transports/index.html#threaded-default) that "*threaded+http*" is the default transport for **raven** is it also true for **raven.contrib.django.handlers.SentryHandler**?

Answer (score 2):

it depends on your Django settings, look at the settings variable `RAVEN_CONFIG`:

```
RAVEN_CONFIG = {
   'dsn': "<transport>://<sentry_url>"
}
```

if your  is "**threaded+https**" or "**threaded+http**" then the answer is yes!